Show that $f(x)$ is bounded below on the constraint set if and only if $c \in R(Q)$
Consider the equality constrained optimization problem:
\begin{equation*}
    \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x) = c^T x \quad \text{subject to} \quad \frac{1}{2}x^TQx=1.
\end{equation*}
where $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, and $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ in non-zero. Let $Q$ be non-zero, diagonal and postive semi-definite (PSD). Show that $f(x)$ is bounded below on the constraint set if and only if $c \in R(Q)$ (range of matrix Q).
My Attempt:
(a) Assume that ( f(x) ) is bounded below on the constraint set $S = \{ x \mid \frac{1}{2}x^T Q x = 1 \} $. Since $Q$ is non-zero, diagonal and PSD, we can write it as
\begin{equation*}
    Q = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_s, 0 , \ldots , 0), \text{ where } \lambda_i > 0, \forall i=1, \ldots ,s.
\end{equation*}
Define $c=(c_1, c_2, \ldots , c_s, c_{s+1}, \ldots , c_n)^T$. Then $c \in R(Q) \ \ \iff \ \ c_{s+1}= \ldots = c_n =0. $ Assume that $c_{s+1}\neq 0$. Fix $x= t \cdot e_{s+1}$, then we have $f(x) = t \cdot c_{s+1}$. Now consider the following:

If $c_{s+1} > 0, $ then $f(x) \to - \infty $ as $t \to - \infty$.
If $c_{s+1} < 0, $ then $f(x) \to - \infty $ as $t \to  \infty$.

As both of these cases show that $f$ is not bounded below, this gives us a contradiction. Hence $c \in R(Q)$.
(b) Suppose that $ c \in R(Q) $. Then from previous case we know that $c_{s+1}= \ldots = c_n =0$. Also, there exists some constant vector $ y \in \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $ c = Q y $. Thus, we have
$$
   f(x) = c^T x = (Q y)^T x = y^T Q x.
   $$Assume that $f$ is not bounded below. Fix $x = t e_1$, where $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we have $f(x) = \lambda_1 y_1t$. Then as $t \to \infty$, $f \to -\infty$, if $\lambda_1 < 0$ and $y_1 >0$. Which is a contradiction because $\lambda_1 \geq 0$ because Q is PSD.
Can someone please tell me if my solution is correct or not? Thanks

What does $R(Q)$ mean?

@GerryMyerson Sorry, I should have mentioned that. It is range of matrix Q.

Your part (a) is essentially correct. I would make two small points:

I would make here is that you only showed the result when $c_{s+1} \neq 0$, when it's not clear that $c_{s+1} \neq 0$. Of course, the same argument applies to any other coordinate beyond $c_s$, and because $c \notin R(Q)$, at least one coordinate must be non-zero, but this should be stated in the proof.

The assumption that the diagonal of $Q$ is eventually $0$ is similarly not necessarily true. While appropriate conjugation by permutation matrices will make this true, it is still a step that may not be considered trivial enough to not even mention it.


You could avoid both of these points by asserting that one of $Q$'s diagonal entries is $0$, call it $c_i$, then applying the $c_{s+1}$ argument to $c_i$ instead. I think this would make your proof cleaner and more readable to boot.
Your part (b) definitely doesn't work, and is difficult to follow. You fix $x = te_1$ and consider $f(x)$ as $t \to \infty$, but what makes you think that $x^\top Qx = 1$ as $t \to \infty$? Indeed, given $\lambda_1 > 0$, we will have $x^\top Q x = \lambda_1 t^2$, which means that $x^\top Q x = 1$ only for $t = \lambda_1^{-1/2}$.
I would, instead, assume $c \in R(Q)$, define $y$ as you did, and use Cauchy-Schwarz for the positive-semidefinite bilinear form $\langle p, q \rangle = p^\top Qq$. In particular, we see that
$$(y^\top Q x)^2 \le (y^\top Q y)(x^\top Qx) = y^\top Q y.$$
This establishes both an upper and lower bound on $f$.
